# Import pfx certificate created on XP to Windows 2008

Tags: windows-7, certificate, x509certificate, windows-server-2008-r2, mmc

I'm trying to import a certificate generated in XP into the machine store on a Windows 2008 box but get an error close to "network password is incorrect ... or private key needs cryptographic service provider not installed."  I also get the same message in Windows 7.

The cert was created with:

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=name" -cy end -a sha1 -sky exchange -ic "authority.cer" -iv "authority.pvk" -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv "name.pvk" "name.cer"
```

The RSA SChannel crypto provider is listed on the Server 2008 box under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider so it seems to be installed.

This was all first attempted with an installer action using X509Certificate2 which has obviously worked fine on XP since.  I've fallen back to trying it manually with the certificates snap-in which fails as stated above.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing and exporting the certificates in Windows 2003 produced certs that could be imported on Server 2008 and 7 manually through the Certificates mmc snap-in and by loading them with X509Certificate2.  The new certificates could be imported manually in XP but not with the X509Certificate2 class.

The end solution for compatibility across all version of Windows was to maintain two versions of the certificates.  One for XP/2003 and another for Vista/7/2008.